# Why py and not pyc or pyo?

Tags: package-management, python

When I install a python deb package, say `python-numpy` the files are plain python files. How do I tell to the package manager -- that I actually would rather use pyc or even better -- pyo files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### You already have them and you're already using them

Well-packaged Python applications are being compiled to `.pyc` files in a script run *after* installation of the files has taken place. This is needed according to the packaging guidelines to be able to adopt to the Python installation you're using at that moment. Do remember that `.pyc` files are very specific to your system (Python version and dependencies).

All `.pyo` and `.pyc` files are therefore specifically excluded in packages and [tagged as errors by Lintian](http://lintian.debian.org/tags/package-installs-python-bytecode.html):

> Compiled python source files must not be included in the package. These files should be removed from the package and created at package installation time in the postinst.
>
> Refer to [Debian Python Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/) section 2.6 ([Modules Byte-Compilation](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-module_packages.html#s-byte_compilation)) for details.
>
> Severity: serious, Certainty: certain

In the case of `python-numpy` this post-install byte-compilation is handled by the debhelper hook of pycentral. After installation it looks like this:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     47 Mar 20  2012 add_newdocs.py -> ../../../../share/pyshared/numpy/add_newdocs.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 251912 Aug  6 22:06 add_newdocs.pyc
```

### Some more background information

The reason for why these `.pyc`/`.pyo` files aren't compiled at runtime during the first application startup as you expected is the following.

The Python files are installed in a system-wide directory, available for all users on the system. Whenever a user starts the application, the Python interpreter can read the `.py` files, but it can't write to the directories (e.g. `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`). This is part of general security in all Linux systems; users shouldn't write to `/usr`, only with root rights this should be possible. For this reason, the APT hooks will compile the Python files for you at installation time; firstly to minimize the package size, secondly to be able to retrigger the hooks once something changes on your system regarding Python, because it's required to recompile when they get incompatible during upgrades for example.

This won't, however, affect regular user-owned python files being compiled at runtime.

Comment: So I should make `/usr/share/pyshared/` writable to myself -- in order to enable python to compile files on the first run.

Comment: @Adobe What? no! Never make these system directories writeable for users. Your package management already compiled them for you (as per what I was trying to say in my answer). Now updated to be more clear about it.

Comment: You now -- that I've just look at the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy` -- there are `pyc` files. I remember I looked there on seveal installations -- and there were just plain py files. So I sort of "can't reproduce the bug".

Comment: The only reason for why the `.pyc` wouldn't be there yet is that the package wasn't installed completely. After unpacking there are other steps to take. IIRC the python-central hook is run only after all packages are installed. So, in a running or interrupted APT session installing the package the observation you described can be made probably.